# Dart: Why is an async error not caught when it is thrown in the constructor body?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

```dart
main() async {
  try {
    final t = Test();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  } catch (e) {
    // Never printed
    print("caught");
  }
}

void willThrow() async {
  throw "error";
}

class Test {
  Test() {
    willThrow();
  }
}
```

If the "async" keyword is removed from `willThrow` everything works as expected.

Is it because you can't await a constructor? If so is there anyway to catch async errors in a constructor body?

Comment: I am a little confused about what you are trying to do here with your code. the Async keyword is typically used in conjunction with the await keyword while it waits on a slow process to complete. I am wondering how your willThrow function is resulting in a future?

Comment: This is just a minimal reproduction of the full problem. Essentially I am calling an "initialise" function in the constructor body which reaches out to an external api. I am then awaiting the same future on the line after. This initialise could throw an error. The above code shows the problem. If the async keyword is added to "willThrow" then the error is never caught, even though it will have executed before the try block is finished.

Comment: because `willThrow()` is an async function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this a go:

```
void main() async {
  try {
    final t = Test();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  } catch (e) {
    // Never printed
    print("caught");
  }
}

Future<void> willThrow() async {
  throw "error";
}

class Test {
  Test() {
    willThrow().catchError((e){print('Error is caught here with msg: $e');});
  }
}
```

As to the 'why':

You use a normal try/catch to catch the failures of awaited asynchronous computations. But since you cannot await the constructor, you have to register the callback that handles the exception in another way. I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you never awaited the Future that was returned from willThrow(), and you never used the result of the Future, any exception thrown by the function is discarded.

There is no way to write an asynchronous constructor.  So you are stuck with using old-school callbacks to handle errors, or simulate an async constructor with a static method:

```
void main() async {
  try {
    final t = await Test.create();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  } catch (e) {
    // Never printed
    print("caught");
  }
}

Future<void> willThrow() async {
  throw "error";
}

class Test {
  Test._syncCreate() {}
  Future<void> _init() async {
    await willThrow();
  }
  static Test create() async {
    Test result = Test._syncCreate();
    await result._init();
    return result;
  }
}
```